# Function reference unavailable within IIFE?

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

If I run the following:

```
var fn = function(){}

(function(){
    fn();
}());
```

It throws an "TypeError: undefined is not a function" in Chrome, and "TypeError: fn is not a function" in Firebug.

Shouldn't `fn` be available in this scope chain, without having to do `window.fn`?

The bizarre part is that if I run:

```
var fn = function(){}
console.log(fn);

(function(){
fn();
}());
```

Then it behaves as expected: `fn` is logged as a function, and no error is thrown in either Chrome or Firefox.

This is making me feel silly, like I shouldn't ever claim to understand JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add semicolon:

```
var fn = function(){};

(function(){
    fn();
}());
```

Comment: Ha, I was just answering it myself when you posted!

Answer (score 1):

Damn, it was ASI.

```
var fn = function(){};

(function(){
fn();
}());
```

Comment: Way to answer your own question, literally. +1 ;-)